# How to add history in my this.props? For push to link

Tags: reactjs

```
  changeRoutePath = (e) =>{
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.onClose();
      this.props.history.push('/company/orgStructure');
 };
 <Link
        to={{
          pathname: '/company/orgStructure',
          state: {
            fromNotifications: true
                 }
          }}
         onClick={(e) => this.changeRoutePath(e)}>
       Prevent
</Link>
```

I have error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Need to go on /company/orgStructure page and take some info in state! How to do it?
If i use just link without onclick i cant use this.props.onClose for close modal. How to push info and go to orgStructure?
**console.log(this.props);**

```
bgClose: false
className: ""
container: true
employeeCode: "00-005424"
escClose: false
onClose: ƒ ()
open: true
showModalEmployeeShortProfile: ƒ ()
stack: true
template: null
title: "Профиль сотрудника"
width: 960
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your component is not bind with react-router-dom you won't be getting their methods in your props, here you don't have access to location, history and match in your props which are props from react router which means your component is not connected with router.

you just have to import withRouter from react router dom which is a HOC and wrap your component in it, than you'll have access to history in your props.

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
class yourComponent extends React.Component{
render(){}
}
export default withRouter(yourComponent)
```

Comment: class ModalEmployeeShortProfile extends React.Component {}   


export default wrapModal(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ModalEmployeeShortProfile));
if i already use that what i need to do?

Comment: export default wrapModal(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(withRouter(ModalEmployeeShortProfile)));

Comment: Thnx! did you know how to remove after my func this.props.location.state?

Comment: Can i also do target="_blank" for this?